# What is the injective envelope of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module

> In the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, what is the injective envelope of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

I was hoping to find a divisible group containing $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that it is also an essential extension. We already know that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrowtail \prod_{i \in \lbrace 1,\ldots,n \rbrace}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})_i  $. But is this an essential extension? I can't prove or disprove it.

Guessing by the 'size' of it ($\prod_{i \in \lbrace 1,\ldots,n \rbrace}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})_i   $), i don't think that it is the right answer.

Also, is there an algorithm sort of thing for finding injective envelope for modules over arbitrary rings.

Comment: what is your explicit embedding?

Comment: well, for every element $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$,we choose any element in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ whose order divides order of $a$, then we get a group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}a \to  \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ then since $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is injective,we get a map from $ \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and from universal property of direct products,we get a map from $ \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} \to \prod \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$.this map is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The injective envelope is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}]/\mathbb{Z}$

We define $$[k]\mapsto \frac{k}{n} +\mathbb{Z}$$

we must show that this is an essential extension and that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}]/\mathbb{Z}$ is injective (for groups =divisible)

First a typical element of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}]/\mathbb{Z}$ is $\frac{a}{n^l}+\mathbb{Z}$ with $n\not | a$. And multiplying by  $n^{l-1}$ we get $\frac{a}{n}+\mathbb{Z}$ and this is an element of the image of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (and is $\neq 0$ since $n\not | a$).

To show that  $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}]/\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible take first the case where $p$ is a prime not dividing $n$ then to divide $\frac{1}{n^l}+\mathbb{Z}$ by $p$ there are $a$ and $b$ such $pa+bn^l=1$ then

$$p\frac{a}{n^l}+\mathbb{Z}=\frac{1}{n^l}-\frac{bn^l}{n^l}+\mathbb{Z}=
\frac{1}{n^l}+\mathbb{Z}$$

On the other hand if $p|n$ then let $n=mp$

$$p\frac{m}{n^{l+1}}+\mathbb{Z}= \frac{1}{n^l}+\mathbb{Z}$$

This shows that  $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}]/\mathbb{Z}$ is an essential, divisible extension of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: how does a typical element of $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]/\mathbb{Z}$ of the form $a/n^{i} + \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\not | a$

Comment: googling the question, came across this,http://www.math.kochi-u.ac.jp/docky/kogi/kogi2010_1/chushodaisu2010/coho06.pdf

Comment: @user2902293 Any element is of the form $a/n^i$ if $n|a$ then write it as $b/n^{i-1}$. As for the apparent discrepancy with the link the two modules are the same the embedding the notation is just different where I have $1/n, 2/n \cdots$ he has $1,2\cdots$

Comment: isn't  $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]$ polynomial ring with indeterminate $1/n$,going modulo $\mathbb{Z}$ 'absorbs' the constant term of the formal polynomial expression.Otherwise it still remains a formal polynomial sum with entries of the type $a_{1}(1/n) + \ldots + a_{k}(1/n)^k$.

Comment: yes but the expression you give is equal to $(a_1n^{k-1}+\dots +a_k)/n^k$

Comment: right. got it.my bad.

Comment: @user2902293 By the way, this ring can be identified with $\bigcup \mathbb{Z}_{n^k}$

Answer (score 1):

If $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots p_k^{a_k}$ is the decomposition of $n$ into (distinct) prime powers, we know that
$$\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
\frac{\Z}{n\Z}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k \frac{\Z}{p_i^{a_i}\Z},
$$
so we just need to find the injective envelope of $\Z/p^a\Z$, for a prime $p$. This is well known to be the Prüfer $p$-group $\Z(p^\infty)$. Thus the answer is
$$
\bigoplus_{i=1}^k \Z(p_i^\infty).
$$

This is a particular case of the following. If $M$ is an artinian $R$-module, we can write the socle of $M$ (the sum of all simple submodules of $M$) as
$$
\bigoplus_{i=1}^k S_i
$$
for a suitable set $\{S_1,S_2,\dots,S_k\}$ of simple submodules of $M$. Then the injective envelope of $M$ is $\bigoplus_{i=1}^k E(S_i)$, where $E(S)$ is the injective envelope of $S$. There is no general method for computing the injective envelope of an arbitrary module over an arbitrary ring.